# Can't assign value to var using Observable, Firebase (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I cant assign value to any var from the return of the subscribe, my observable name is `reportess` and I trying to assign the value to var in the same service that I declared the observable from external component. In the other hand I can print by log the return of the subscribe.

Service:

```
import { Injectable, Input } from '@angular/core';
//Archivo json
import _reportes from "../archivos json/reportes.json";
import _vacio from "../archivos json/vacio.json";
//Exportador pdf
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
//firebase

import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
import {Subject} from 'rxjs'


@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicesService {
     @Input() reportes
    coleccionReporte: AngularFirestoreCollection<Reporte>;
    reportess: Observable<Reporte[]>;
    reportesMargis;
    reportesDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Reporte>;
    ColeccionDeReportes;
    Reporte;

    constructor(public firebase:AngularFirestore) { 
    this.reportess = firebase.collection('reporte').valueChanges(); 
    console.log(this.reportes)
}
```

Component:

```
constructor(private reportesServices:ServicesService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
    this.reportesServices.reportess.subscribe(data => {this.reportesServices.reportes = data} ); //dont work  
    this.reportesServices.reportess.subscribe(data => {console.log(data)} ); //work
}
```

Comment: How do you know that the first example doesn't work? Because `console.log(this.reportes)` in the last line of `ServicesService` shows you `undefined`?

Comment: yes 'console.log(this.reportes)' line show undefined

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `@Input()` for `service` properties. Just remove that.

It should be used only in a `component` or a `directive`.

```
export class ServicesService {
      reportes;  // removed input decorator
      coleccionReporte: AngularFirestoreCollection<Reporte>;
      reportess: Observable<Reporte[]>;
      reportesMargis;
      reportesDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Reporte>;
      ColeccionDeReportes;
      Reporte;



     ..........
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Amit Chigadani have noticed above you have to remove `@Input` decorator from your `reportes` property. It is public and will be accessible from `ServicesService` instance. So, the code

```
this.reportesServices.reportess.subscribe(data => {
    this.reportesServices.reportes = data
});
```

should work. Your `console.log(this.reportes)` shows `undefined` because this line is executed before the observable resolves.

---

However, such logic looks a bit weird because the service stuff is executed outside of service. I'd propose to refactor your service code a bit:

```
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

this.reportess = firebase.collection('reporte').valueChanges().pipe(
    tap(data => this.reportes = data)
);
```

so the storing will be handled inside the service.

Comment: You should import it (`import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';`). I've edited my answer. But this is just refactoring. The original code above should work either. Put your console log into a timeout to be sure that it is executed after the observable completes and you will see `setTimeout(() => console.log(this.reportes), 5000)`. This is a dirty trick but just to show you.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
Thanks for all the answers.
I declared the 'test' with 'let'. In the service I declared a method to force the cast of the recived data to my objects.

component:

```
 constructor(private reportesServices:ServicesService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        let test: any

        this.reportesServices.reportess.subscribe(
          data => {
            test = data;
            this.reportesServices.setReporters(test);
          });         
      }
```

Service:

```
setReporters(data){
    this.reportes  = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
      let reporte:Reporte = {
        titulo: data[i].titulo,
        fecha: data[i].fecha,
        ruta: data[i].ruta,
        prioridad: data[i].prioridad,
        funcion: data[i].funcion,
        comentario: data[i].comentario,
        solucionado: data[i].solucionado    
      };
      this.reportes.push(reporte)
    }  
  }
```